# Would like to skip files during a GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, directory

So, we are working on a overhaul on our website. Currently, the articles, posts, etc are files on the server, now we want the contents of the file in our database. While testing we need to periodically get new file contents.

Here's what I have (I just included the articleConvertedPath

```
var articlesConvertedPath = @"D:\articles\ArticlesConverted";
var articlesConvertedDir = new DirectoryInfo(articlesConvertedPath);
var articlesConvertedFiles = articlesConvertedDir.GetFiles();

var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\articles);
var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbSelected].ConnectionString;
var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
con.Open();

foreach (var currFile in dirInfo.GetFiles(".asp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
if (!articlesConvertedFiles.Contains(currFile))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currFile.FullName))
    {
        OutputTextBox.Text += currFile.Name.Replace(".asp", string.Empty) + "\r\n";
        var articleText = sr.ReadToEnd()
            .Replace("<!--#include file=\"../include/engine_article_header.asp\"-->", string.Empty)
            .Replace("<!--#include file=\"../include/engine_article_footer.asp\"-->", string.Empty);

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateArticleContent", con))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ArticleID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currFile.Name.Replace(".asp", string.Empty);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ArticleText", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = articleText;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    var copyFilePath = string.Format(@"D:\articles\ArticlesConverted\{0}", currFile.Name);
    File.Copy(currFile.FullName, copyFilePath);
}
```

You can see that I tried to do !articlesConvertedFiles.Contains(currFile), but that really doesn't work well as the program still has to get EVERY file (a little more than 18k files).

QUESTION:Is there anyway this could be improved? Just so you know, this is a development tool that we use before we go live. So the code doesn't need to look pretty.

Anyways... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) which will just only load the required files following way:

```
foreach(var currFile in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(".asp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                               .Where(x=> !articlesConvertedFiles.Contains(x))
{
}
```

Another benefit of this will be that the files information will be loaded when the foreach loop will start it's first iteration.

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason, it never hits anything in the foreach